# How can i put result to 'add' variable by passing num1, num2 values as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm a learner in the typescript lang .
is there any way to put addition result direcly in the 'add' variable .

```
  let add = (number:{n1:number, n2:number})=>
    {
        console.log("addition" + number.n1+number.n2);
    };
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly. I doubt this has anything to do with your question, but with order of operations is going to be `("addition" + number.n1) + number.n2`

Comment: What is the expected result? Maybe that would clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for this:

1. `const add = (n1:number, n2:number) => ({n1, n2, add: n1+n2})`

or

2. `const add = (n:{n1:number, n2:number}) => ({...n, add: n.n1+n.n2})`

In the 1st case you pass 2 numbers and obtain a json with 3 elements

In the 2nd case you pass a json with 2 element and obtain a the same json + the 3rd element

```js
const add1 = (n1, n2) => ({n1: n1, n2: n2, add: n1+n2})
console.log(add1(1,2))

const add2 = (n) => ({...n, add: n.n1+n.n2})
console.log(add2({n1:1, n2:2}))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want `add` to return the actual result of the mathematical addition of the two given numbers?! In that case this might be what you are looking for:

```
let add = (number: {n1: number, n2: number}): number => number.n1 + number.n2;

console.log(add({n1: 1, n2: 2})); // 3
```

There is no difference in plain JavaScript whatsoever:

```js
let add = (number) => number.n1 + number.n2;

console.log(add({n1: 1, n2: 2}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what you are asking exactly. I would write it to look like

```
interface myNumber {
  n1: number;
  n2: number;
}

const add = (num : myNumber) : number => {
  return num.n1 + num.n2;
}

const subtract = ({ n1, n2 } : myNumber) : number => {
  return n1 - n2;
}

const foo: myNumber= { n1: 4, n2: 2 };
console.log(add(foo));
console.log(subtract(foo));
```